# Why Validation message not go unless I re-write both inputs valid input with invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have implemented remote validation on two inputs it works the problem if on of the input is not valid the message will not be deleted unless I re-write both inputs valid input with invalid

```
    [Required]
    [Remote("IsSectionAvailable", "Test", AdditionalFields = "Section", ErrorMessage = "this section already exists in this year", HttpMethod = "POST")]
        public Nullable<short> Year { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Remote("IsSectionAvailable", "Test", AdditionalFields = "Year", ErrorMessage = "this section already exists in this year", HttpMethod = "POST")]
        public string Section { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult IsSectionAvailable(string Section, short? Year)
        {
           if (!Year.HasValue)
            {
                return Json(true);
            }    
             return Json(!IsSectionExists(Section, Year.Value));
        }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "validation not go"?

Comment: @derloopkat this message (this section already exists in this year) will not be deleted

Comment: Well, both fields are calling same method with same parameters. What did you expected? If you want validators to work independently then create one for section and one for year.